How to compile Steinberg ASIO SDK on Window?
I want to compile a simple program using ASIO SDK, however there is a strange error that I cannot fix.
#include "asio.h"

int main(void)
{
    ASIODriverInfo info {};

    ASIOInit(&info);

    return 0;
}

In this portion of code I call the ASIOInit(ASIODriverInfo *info) function and i cause this error:
asiosdk/common/asiodrvr.cpp:16:2: error: #error do not use this
   16 | #error do not use this
      |  ^~~~~

and when I check in the asiodrvr.cpp file, I found this code:
#if WINDOWS
#error do not use this
AsioDriver::AsioDriver (LPUNKNOWN pUnk, HRESULT *phr) : CUnknown("My AsioDriver", pUnk, phr)
{
}

If I erase it it works but i'm not supposed to modify the SDK, so do you know what is the correct way to avoid this error ?
My configuration is as follows:
OS: Window 11
compiler: g++ (MinGW64)
compile with: handmade makefile
c++ version: 23
compiler flags: -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic
I try to remove the error, but it's not correct for the portability I guess,
I refer to the documentation(PDF) in th SDK file, unsuccessful.

You should not be including asiodrvr.cpp in your build.  At least, I think so.  I only build with the following files:
asio.cpp
asiodrivers.cpp
asiolist.cpp

Try with those, see how you go.  ASIO started out with the intention of being cross-platform, but, AFAIK, is now Windows only.

Thank you very much, it works, however, how do I know which file to include?
I thought I had to compile all the cpp files.

I can't remember how I figured it out - it was years ago.  Might be in the docs, IDK
